# Starter won't engage the flywheel

Tags: honda, accord

Driving home my car just died. Try restarting it, starter motor just spins. No grinding,no clicking, just spinning freely, but wouldn't engage flywheel. Hot another starter figuring this one was shot, preventing it from engaging the flywheel, and in the meantime, 3 days, the battery dies completely. Put the other starter on, and did the same thing. Was told battery probably just wasn't strong enough to power starter enough. Charging battery now. Any other reasons why it just wouldn't engage flywheel? It's not grinding it, so that means it's not engageing it at all, right??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I think this answer would help you out:
[Flywheel Spins, but doesn't engage: possible causes](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/44859/if-my-starter-is-spinning-but-not-engaging-flywheel-what-is-the-issue)

Answer (score 2):

OK you didn't bother to share the year, make, and model of your "car". So a *definitive* answer will be impossible. But I'm just this side of certain it's your bendix -- the part that moves the starter gear into your flywheel. Depending on the year, make, and model. These are sometimes actuated by an *external* solenoid.

HTH

Comment: Agreed.  OP, here's a handy little video that shows how the starter is supposed to work, and why your solenoid (bendix) being fried would still let your starter motor spin but not engage the flywheel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFsl5r34lCI